# Is the following set bounded?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization

Is the following set bounded?

$$\{(x,y): x^
2 + xy + y^
2 = 6\}$$

How can I draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is bounded since it is an ellipse. If you make the substitution $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$, the equation becomes 
$$
(u+v)^2+(u+v)(u-v)+(u-v)^2=6,
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
3u^2+v^2=6,
$$
or 
$$
\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{v^2}6=1.
$$
So your region is an ellipse, centered at the origin, with axes of length $2\sqrt2$ and $2\sqrt6$, rotated so that the axes are at 45 degrees from the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear